# Idiomatic way of resolving nested mutable borrow conflct

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Consider the minimal example below, which presents a situation I encountered in some real code:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;
type HS = HashSet<String>;

fn fn1(x: String, hs0: &mut HS, hs1: &mut HS) {
    // ...
}

fn fn0(hs0: &mut HS, hs1: &mut HS) {
    hs0.get("").map(|x| fn1(x.clone(), hs0, hs1));
}

fn main() {
    let mut hs0 = HS::new();
    let mut hs1 = HS::new();
    fn0(&mut hs0, &mut hs1);
}
```

The borrow checker is not happy:

```
error[E0500]: closure requires unique access to `hs0` but `*hs0` is already borrowed
 --> <anon>:9:21
  |
9 |     hs0.get("").map(|x| fn1(x, hs0, hs1));
  |     ---             ^^^        ---      - borrow ends here
  |     |               |          |
  |     |               |          borrow occurs due to use of `hs0` in closure
  |     |               closure construction occurs here
  |     borrow occurs here
```

[**on the Rust playground**](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0fa6c84ccea2598c1054bc65621b3efc&version=stable&backtrace=0)

---

I understand the error message above, and I want to know the idiomatic way of solving this issue. Note that:

- I want `fn0` and `fn1` to be separate functions for readability/testability reasons. (I.e. they make sense alone on their own.)
- I want to call `fn1` from `fn0` with the same arguments in a `.map(...)` chained call.

Is the only sensible option not using `.map`?

Comment: `map` is the least of your issue here. `hs0.get("")` returns a reference into `hs0`, and you want to call `fn1` with (1) this reference and (2) a mutable reference to `hs0`. This is not a tractable requirement, you have to abandon either (1) or (2).

Comment: @MatthieuM. good point - unfortunately I made a mistake while minimizing the real code. I've edited the snippet to more closely resemble the real scenario.

Comment: I think that your edit don't change the point of @MatthieuM. comment.

Comment: I'm not convinced that `map` is idiomatic here anyway, since you are making use of side effects and discarding its result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Roughly speaking, `hs0` remains borrowed until there's no references to any part of it. That is, while `x: &String` lives, you cannot mutably borrow `hs0`. It means we need to do something to end the lifetime of `x`, like convert it into `String` and pass that string into the next `map`.

```
fn fn0(hs0: &mut HS, hs1: &mut HS) {
    hs0.get("").map(|x| x.clone()).map(|x| fn1(x, hs0, hs1));
}
```